# Which continuous functions are polynomials?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, differential-topology

I posted this on the new math.SE website but didn't get much of a response, so I am reposting it here.

Suppose $f$ is a continuous $\mathbb{R}$-valued function on $\mathbb{R}^n$.  What type of conditions on $f$ guarantee it is a polynomial up to homeomorphism. That is, when can I find a homeomorphism $\phi:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\phi^* f = f \circ \phi \in \mathbb{R}[x_1,\ldots, x_n]$?

Some related questions:

- A necessary condition in the case of $n = 1$ is that point inverse images of $f$ must be finite (since a polynomial has only finitely many roots).  Is this sufficient?
- What if we replace $\mathbb{R}$ by $\mathbb{C}$?
- What if we look at smooth functions and diffeomorphism instead?  (I tried playing around with the implicit function theorem but didn't get anywhere).
- What about the complex analytic case?

I'm not quite sure how to tag this, so feel free to edit them.

Comment: In the case $n=1$ a necessary (and I would guess sufficient) condition for $f$ to be expressible as a nonconstant polynomial composed with a homeomorphism is: (1) there are only finite many values of $x$ at which $f(x)$ has a local maximum or minimum and (2) $f$ is proper (i.e. tends to plus or minus infinity at each end of the line). A function like $x+2 sin x$ has finite point preimages but infinitely many local maxima. The case $n=2$ seems much more interesting/harder.

Comment: Topological classification of continuous real functions ($n=1$) may be obtained by considering their intervals of monotonicity. In general, differentiable and analytic classifications are harder than topological. A keyword is "singularity theory". 

Comment: A theorem of Whitney says that every continuous function is homotopic to a smooth one, perhaps one could use this to reduce the question to the case where the original function is smooth? Though I'm not at all sure how you would get a homeomorphism of R^n from the homotopy...

Comment: In the real valued case, $n=1$, a necessary and sufficient condition might be that $f$ makes a finite number of oscillations and is unbounded as $x\to\pm\infty$.

Comment: It would be nice a characterization like this: a continuous $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ is topologically conjugated to a polynomial iff it has finitely many "topological" critical points, and they have finite rank critical groups (to be defined in terms of the relative singular homology in the standard way).

Comment: Is it true that $P(x,y)$ is a polynomial iff all its sections at $x=const$ and $y=const.$ are polynomials?

Comment: $n=1$, smooth: A necessary condition is that there are only finitely many points where $f'=0$ and that each of these has finite multiplicity in the sense that some higher derivative is nonzero at that point.

Comment: I think so. There exists $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and an infinite $S\subset \mathbb{R}$, such that $\deg P(x,\cdot)\leq n$ for all $x\in S.$ Therefore for all $x\in S$ these $P(x,\cdot)$ are determined by the $n+1$ values at $y=0,1\dot,n$. By the Lagrange interpolation formula, $P$ coincides with a polynomial $p\in\mathbb{R}[x,y]$ on the whole set $S\times\mathbb{R}$. But then, for any $y\in\mathbb{R}$, $P(x,y)=p(x,y)$ for all $x$, because they are two polynomials in $x$ coinciding on the infinite set $S$. Is this right?

Comment: I suppose you can say something nice in the complex $n=1$ case: If a continuous map from the Riemann sphere to itself looks locally topologically like a candidate to be a rational map, in the sense that for every point in the codomain there is a punctured neighborhood over which the thing is a covering space, then up to homeomorphism of the domain it is a rational map. (Use the fact that a complex $1$-manifold homeomorphic to the Riemann sphere is isomorphic to the Riemann sphere, plus the fact that a complex-analytic map from the Riemann sphere to itself is a rational map.)

Comment: And (I meant to say) from the special case when only infinity goes to infinity you can read off a characterization of polynomials $\mathbb C\to \mathbb C$ up to homeomorphism of the domain.

Comment: It might be good to begin with a local question: Which germs of real-valued functions are topologically conjugate to polynomials.

Comment: that's a good question too.

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to go out on a limb and make a partial conjecture based on Tom Goodwillie's comment.  A function $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ is topologically conjugate to a polynomial $p(x)$ only if it is topologically conjugate to a continuous function $q(x0$ of finite type which is nowhere constant.  By "finite type" I mean that there is a tiling of $\mathbb{R}^n$ by finitely many convex regions, such that the restriction of $q(x)$ to each region is non-constant and either linear or of the form $1/\phi(x)+c$, where $\phi$ is linear and $c$ is constant.

In this version of the answer, I'm going out on a limb for a second time.  I first conjectured that $q$ should simply be linear on each convex piece, and Richard Borcherds quickly found a counterexample to that in two variables.

I don't mean this to be a sufficient condition, since clearly it is not sufficient when $n=1$.  A "finite type" function in the above sense can be bounded, while a polynomial cannot be bounded.  Maybe it is a sufficient condition as a topological characterization of rational functions with no poles.  For polynomials specifically, there are strong restrictions on the behavior at infinity, but per Richard's example, they are somewhat looser than I first thought.

There is a relevant pair of results due to Whitney and Goresky.  Whitney proved that every analytic variety in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a [Whitney stratified space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitney_conditions).  Goresky proved that every Whitney stratified space in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is supported on a piecewise smooth triangulation (but not necessarily one which is finite type).  It is easy to ride roughshod over subtleties as I already did, but these results seem like a good way to get started with the problem.

The smooth and complex cases of the problem seem more complicated for various reasons.

Comment: I suppose you meant to add that the piece-wise linear function is nowhere constant.

Comment: Oh yes, you are right.


Comment: Here is a possible counterexample to the conjecture above: 

The real polynomial x^2 + (xy-1)^2 is bounded below but does not achieve its lower bound 0, which I think implies that it is not conjugate to a piecewise linear function of finite type. 

Comment: Whoops, clearly my conjecture needs to be adjusted.  I didn't properly think through projectivization of the question.
